# Problem with for loop while querying PubAG API with python

Tags: python, api, for-loop, python-requests

Here is my code, I am trying to get a 100 unique publications for each search term:

```
import requests
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
```

```
search_terms = ['grapes', 'cotton','apple', 'onion','cucumber']
res_data = []
pag_data = []
for i in search_terms[0:5]:
    try:
        api_key = "DEMO_KEY"
        endpoint = 'https://api.nal.usda.gov/pubag/rest/search?query=abstract:'+str(i)
        print(endpoint)
        q_params = {"api_key": api_key, "per_page":100}
        response = requests.get(endpoint, params=q_params)
        print(response)
        r = response.json()
        res_data.append(r)
        print(len(res_data))
        a = res_data[0]['response']
        
    
        
        pag_data.append(a)
        
        print(len(pag_data))
        sleep(5)
        
    except:
        print(i)
        continue
```

Then to create DataFrames

```
pag_dfs = [pd.DataFrame(i['docs']) for i in pag_data]
df = pd.concat(pag_dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

I am getting the 500 publications but only 100 are unique, If I do it one by one it works. How can I improve my for loop to get unique records for each search term?
Docs:https://pubag.nal.usda.gov/apidocs

edit:
I got the for loop to work by adding another for loop for the second list, this adds a lot of duplicates but I then processed it with pandas to get the unique publications for each term.

```
res_data = []
pag_data = []
for i in search_terms:
    try:
        api_key = "DEMO_KEY"
        endpoint = 'https://api.nal.usda.gov/pubag/rest/search?query=abstract:'+str(i)
        print(endpoint)
        q_params = {"api_key": api_key, "per_page":100}
        response = requests.get(endpoint, params=q_params)
        print(response)
        r = response.json()
        res_data.append(r)
        print(len(res_data))
        for x in res_data:
            a = x['response']
            pag_data.append(a)
        
        print(len(pag_data))
        #sleep(2)
        
    except:
        print(i)
        continue
```

Comment: A remark or two about your code: `for i in search_terms[0:5]` is equivalent to `for i in search_terms`. Furthermore you do not need to do `str(i)` seeing as `i` is already a string. You should also use proper names, `i` does not say anything to the reader but `search_term` does. `for search_term in search_terms` reads a lot better than `for i in search_terms`. The `continue` is useless too, the loop will continue without it. You are also always accessing only the first element of `res_data` when doing `res_data[0]['response']`, is that intentional?

Comment: It seems like you've used up the rate of the API_KEY so it makes it difficult to run your code and as such it is difficult to help you. After `r = response.json()` add `if r["error"]: print(r["error"]["message"]); exit(1)` to see the error message sent back by the API.

Comment: Seemingly each call to the constructed endpoint results in 100 publications and as such you are overall collecting 500 collections when using the API for all 5 search terms. I am assuming that there might be duplicate publications fetched and if so you need to filter out all duplicates from those 500 collections. I don't have an API key so I can't say for sure if that's the case.

Comment: @NoName123 yeah the 5 was a subset, for the example, and yes accessing the first key is intentional. And I don't thing I have used up the rate, this example only call the API 5 times, the max for the is 50 per hour. "DEMO_KEY" is actually the public API key so you can try it.

Comment: @NoName123 I was able to make it somewhat work even though it adds a lot of duplicates for each index by adding another for loop for the second list.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments there are things that can be done to improve your code quality.

- `for i in search_terms[0:5]` is equivalent to `for i in search_terms`
- Looping variable name `i` is bad, does not say what it is. Use something better, for example `for term in search_terms`
- You don't have to do `str(i)` seeing as it's already a string
- The `continue` in your `except` block is useless, the for-loop will continue without it too.
- You are also doing unnecessary things such as creating the `res_data` list.

Now to a potential solution. Given the lack of proper details regarding exactly what you want out I have made an assumption or two. With that said, here is a solution that yields the following results that might be what you need:

```
                                              nalt_all  ... pmcid_url
0    [adipose tissue, anthocyanins, aorta, body wei...  ...       NaN
2    [aquaculture, data collection, eco-efficiency,...  ...       NaN
7    [ribosomal DNA, host plants, Xylella fastidios...  ...       NaN
8    [bioactive properties, canola oil, droplet siz...  ...       NaN
10   [Aphidoidea, Bactrocera, Citrus, adults, birds...  ...       NaN
..                                                 ...  ...       ...
472  [Cucumis sativus, Escherichia coli, biosynthes...  ...       NaN
480  [biochemistry, cucumbers, fungicides, hydropho...  ...       NaN
491  [Cucumber mosaic virus, Eisenia fetida, Tobacc...  ...       NaN
494  [Cucumber mosaic virus, RNA libraries, correla...  ...       NaN
499  [Aphidoidea, Capsicum annuum, Cucumber mosaic ...  ...       NaN

[141 rows x 28 columns]

With columns: 
nalt_all, subject, author_lastname, last_modified_date, language, title, startpage, usda_authored_publication, id, text_availability, doi_url, issue, author, format, endpage, journal_name, abstract, pmid_url, url, volume, publication_year, usda_funded_publication, issn, page, author_primary, doi, handle_url, pmcid_url
```

```py
import requests
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

api_key = "DEMO_KEY"
q_params = {"api_key": api_key, "per_page": 100}
# Fetch data from the API
search_terms = ['grapes', 'cotton','apple', 'onion','cucumber']
publications = []
for i, search_term in enumerate(search_terms):
    try:
        endpoint = 'https://api.nal.usda.gov/pubag/rest/search?query=abstract:' + search_term
        response = requests.get(endpoint, params=q_params)
        r = response.json()
        # Here I used the list destructuring operator *
        publications = [*publications, *r["response"]["docs"]]
        # `publications += r["response"]["docs"]` is an equivalent way of merging the lists
        sleep(5)  # Important, don't spam the API
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        print("=" * 50)
        print(f"Failed: {i}, {search_term}, {e}")
        print("=" * 50)

# Merge all the publications (each publication is a dictionary)
pubs = {}
for i, pub in enumerate(publications):
    pubs.update({i: pub})

"""
The creation of the Pandas dataframe
   1) Create the dataframe and specify that we want the keys of the `pubs` dictionary to be the rows of the dataframe by specifying `orient="index"`
   2) We drop all duplicates with respect to the column "issn" from the dataframe. The ISSN is a unique identifier for each publication.
   3) We drop all columns that have all "NaN" because they are useless
   4) We drop the first "date" column as it too seems useless, it only contains "0000".
"""
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pubs, orient="index").drop_duplicates(subset="issn").dropna(axis=1, how='all').drop("date", axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

**EDIT: You can perform the merging of the publication dictionaries in the first loop if you want to, this would make the script faster as it avoids unnecessary work. I skipped it in the above solution so not to complicate it too much. Here is how the code would look if you do that.**

```py
import requests
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

api_key = "DEMO_KEY"
q_params = {"api_key": api_key, "per_page": 100}
# Fetch data from the API
search_terms = ['grapes', 'cotton','apple', 'onion','cucumber']
publications = dict()
j = 0
for i, search_term in enumerate(search_terms):
    try:
        endpoint = 'https://api.nal.usda.gov/pubag/rest/search?query=abstract:' + search_term
        response = requests.get(endpoint, params=q_params)
        r = response.json()
        for publication in r["response"]["docs"]:
            publications.update({j: publication})
            j += 1
        sleep(5)  # Important, don't spam the API
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        print("=" * 50)
        print(f"Failed: {i}, {search_term}, {e}")
        print("=" * 50)

"""
The creation of the Pandas dataframe
   1) Create the dataframe and specify that we want the keys of the `pubs` dictionary to be the rows of the dataframe by specifying `orient="index"`
   2) We drop all duplicates with respect to the column "issn" from the dataframe. The ISSN is a unique identifier for each publication.
   3) We drop all columns that have all "NaN" because they are useless
   4) We drop the first "date" column as it too seems useless, it only contains "0000".
"""
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(publications, orient="index").drop_duplicates(subset="issn").dropna(axis=1, how='all').drop("date", axis=1)
print(df, end="\n\n")
for col in df.columns:
    print(col, end=", ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed solution and it is exactly how I wanted, just to collect publications for each term and store them as a df.

Comment: @Rapha18th Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.